# Scanning the network for all the hostnames present with their respective ip addresses

Tags: linux, networking

I have tried `nmap`, `nbtscan`, `fping`, `arp-scan` for the overstated need and all are producing expected output.

But I am facing some trouble with the `arp` command its not working and showing something like this:

```
? (10.240.253.2) at 80:a1:d7:7c:22:94 [ether] on eth0
<something>.local (10.240.253.53) at 9c:2a:70:d8:50:ed [ether] on eth0
```

I have tried `arp -a` and `arp -a -n` both. Also I tried running `ping -b <broadcast ip address>` before these command but `ping -b` does not execute at all means it does nothing.
On other systems in my network it is running fine. But it seems there is some setting problem with my computer that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

`arp` is not a scanner. It queries your system's ARP cache.

Therefore, it will only show IP and MAC addresses of hosts which have sent ARP queries or answers recently seen by your system.

As you mention, `nmap`, for example, is much more suited to what you're trying to do than `arp`.